# How do I resolve can't resolve mysql2 error in NextJS app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm having this problem where I'm getting constant errors when I try to run my `Next.js` app. This has never happened before. It's saying it can't find modules. At first, it said it couldn't resolve '`fs`'. I found a thread that indicated a way to fix this problem by changing the `next.js.config` file to the following:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    // Fixes npm packages that depend on `fs` module
    if (!isServer) {
      config.node = {
        fs: "empty",
      };
    }

    return config;
  },
};
```

Then after that, it couldn't resolve 'net' so I added `net: "empty"` to the next.js.config file. Then it was aws-sdk. Then mysql. I actually just went ahead and installed those packages on my app's backend. Now, it's saying it can't resolve mysql2.

I'm really lost as to what's going wrong and how to resolve this. Can anyone help?

This first started happening after I did a dynamic import:

```
const SelectedProductPage = dynamic(
  () => import("../../components/customerView/SignUp/SelectedProduct"),
  { ssr: false }
);
```

Comment: What Next.js version are you using?

Comment: "next": "10.0.9"